# How can I add a href link to another page in DjangoCMS index page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I have a website developed using DjangoCMS and I tried to add a `href` to another page (site.com/en/blog). Unforunately none of my tries went well:

**urls.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf.urls import *  # NOQA
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps': {'cmspages': CMSSitemap}}),
    url(r'^select2/', include('django_select2.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^blog', include('cms.urls')),
)


# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  # NOQA
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        ) + staticfiles_urlpatterns() + urlpatterns  # NOQA
```

**index.html**

```
...
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="blog-3col.html">3 Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-2col.html">2 Columns</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-2col2.html">2 Columns with sidebar</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-classic.html">Standard</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-full.html">Fullwidth</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-modern.html">Modern</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog-modern2.html">Modern 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Modern 2 Lite</a></li>
    </ul>
...
```

I've tried the following:

`<a href="blog.html">Blog</a>` or
`<a href="{% url 'blog.html' %}">Blog</a>` or
`<a href="{% url blog.html %}">Blog</a>`

But every time I get `404-Page not found`. I am sure that the page exists at that path.

Any hints, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually writing the menus yourself, you should use the [`{% show_menu %}`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/navigation.html#show-menu) template tag in django CMS.

If you need to have non-CMS menu nodes too, look at how to [extend the menu](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/how_to/menus.html) in django CMS.

Comment: That means that I have to modify the entire menu, which I think it will take some time, right ? I'd like the menu to be more CMS based but I didn't get too much from that documentation

Comment: Yes it'll take some time to set up, but it'll be worth it. One of the big advantages of using django CMS is the auto-generated menu. If you need help setting it up, feel free to pop into #django-cms on irc.freenode.net for help.

Comment: I've tried to enter that channel but nobody answered me. Another question, If I will integrate that menu, the style and html will remain the same as it is in the template ?

Comment: I'm sitting there right now waiting for you ;-). It's IRC so after asking your question you'll have to occasionally wait a while for people to wake up etc. 

You can use custom style/html with the menu system.